# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512

Tags: oracle

I try to write a stored procedure so that the transaction number returns to 01 every day, but when I run it, all transaction numbers on that day to 01 don't increase.

then I add

`and (V_JML_RECORD = 1) THEN
      V_JML_RECORD: = V_JML_RECORD +1;`

and when I run it, I get an `ORA-01422` error occurs; is there an exact exact return on requested number of rows that can explain and provide a solution to my problem?

```
SELECT   TRIM (NAMA), TRIM (KD_KTR) AS KDKTR
INTO   V_NAMA, V_KDKTR
FROM   D_PRS
WHERE   TRIM (STB) = P_STB;

SELECT TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'MM') 
INTO V_BLNSKR
from dual;


SELECT TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'DD') 
INTO V_HRSKR
from dual;

SELECT COUNT(NOKAS) 
INTO V_JML_RECORD
FROM (
SELECT NOKAS,TGKAS,KTRASL FROM D_MSTHEADER_UKERJA WHERE TGKAS IN(
SELECT MAX(TGKAS) FROM D_MSTHEADER_UKERJA WHERE KTRASL=V_KDKTR)
)

IF (V_BLNSKR = '02')
AND (V_HRSKR = '27') THEN
  V_JML_RECORD := 1;

  ELSIF (V_BLNSKR = '02')
         AND (V_HRSKR = '27')
        AND (V_JML_RECORD = 1) THEN
 V_JML_RECORD := V_JML_RECORD +1;
 ELSE
   V_JML_RECORD := V_JML_RECORD +1;

  END IF;
```

Comment: As your error message say, the error should come from this query `SELECT   TRIM (NAMA), TRIM (KD_KTR) AS KDKTR
INTO   V_NAMA, V_KDKTR
FROM   D_PRS
WHERE   TRIM (STB) = P_STB;`. Try debug it without the line `INTO   V_NAMA, V_KDKTR` and you would see it return more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

To immediately resolved your issue add the ROWNUM= 1 on query below, but the correct way is for you to check which is the correct row to get by examining the result of your original query. You only have to fetch a SINGLE ROW query when using INTO function.

```
SELECT   TRIM (NAMA), TRIM (KD_KTR) AS KDKTR
INTO   V_NAMA, V_KDKTR
FROM   D_PRS
WHERE   TRIM (STB) = P_STB AND ROWNM = 1;
```